# SheetJS js-xlsx - SheetJS is auto formatting my column with percentage value

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, export-to-excel, sheetjs

I have the following HTML tables and Javascript function, using SheetJS to parse the tables then export them to an excel file.

```js
var tablesToExcel = (function() {

    return function(tables, wsnames, wbname) {

        var workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

        for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
            var ws1 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById(tables[i]));
            console.log(ws1);
            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, ws1, wsnames[i]);
        }
        XLSX.writeFile(workbook, wbname);
    }
})();
```

```html
<table id="po-table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"> Operating Unit</th>
        <th scope="col"> Rate </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Leyte</td>
      <td>90%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="cert-table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"> Operating Unit</th>
        <th scope="col"> Rate </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Samar</td>
      <td>100%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="tablesToExcel(['po-table', 'cert-table'], ['PO', 'Cert'], 'PO Report.xls')"  class="btn btn-success btn-lg mb-5" id="downloadTable" type="button"> Export as Excel</button>
```

The expected output should display **90%** in the column but in reality, the result shown on the column from the generated excel file was **0.9**.

Is there any way that I can format the columns or disable this auto formatting by SheetJS?

Answer (score 6):

Add {raw: true}, it will keep the raw string

var ws1 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById(tables[i]), {raw: true});